# How to call a HTTP GET method in Alfresco Activiti Workflow?

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I have to validade some data before starting a new Activiti Workflow in Alfresco. This validation is called by a HTTP GET method. If validation fails, I must throw an exception and stop the workflow creation.

Is it possible to call a HTTP GET method on startEvent in my process definition file (.bpmn20.xml)? How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the first task of your business process a service task:

```
    <startEvent id="start" activiti:formKey="..."></startEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="start" targetRef="validate" />
    <serviceTask id="validate" name="Validate" activiti:delegateExpression="${ValidateDelegate}" />
```

Create a spring manged bean of class `ValidateDelegate` (class name matters) extending `org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.BaseJavaDelegate`. Override the execute  method and implement your validation there. Throw the exception if you feel the need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andreas! Doing it this way, am I able to abort the workflow before it starts? I mean, throwing an exception message to the user?

Comment: Answering myself, yes, I am able to throw an exception and abort the workflow implementing your approach! Thanks once again!